# How to compare value of the same Enumeration? (== comparison does not work!)

Tags: swift, enums, compiler-errors, switch-statement, equality

Looks like Enumerations in Swift cannot be compared for equality. Here is the code I would expect to work:

```
let areEqual = MyEnum.SomeEnumValue == MyEnum.SomeEnumValue
```

However, this does not compile and throws error: `Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(MyEnum, MyEnum)'`.

Is it possible to compare 2 Enumeration values using `==` operator or do I really write switch-case for that?

---

**EDIT**

Here is self containing example. Just past it to playground and you should see the compilation error.

```
import UIKit

enum MyEnum {
    case SomeValue(Int)
    case OtherValue(Double)
    case ThirdValue
}

let areEqual = MyEnum.ThirdValue == MyEnum.ThirdValue
```

Looks a bit like Swift bug because it lets you compare Enumerations that has no associated values without complains. So I hope this is not expected behaviour (allowing to compare some Enumerations but not others).

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Can you show a (minimal) complete, self-contained example (including the enum definition) ? Also it is unclear (to me) if you want to compare enumeration constants or the values of variables.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: @Martin R Working on it. Just a moment.

Comment: @MartinR why it is working for first case without intializer values

Comment: @Martin MyEnum.Third is just as simple as it could possibly be. And I am only comparing that one.

Comment: @drasto: `MyEnum.ThirdValue` is an expression of the type `MyEnum`, and as stated in the answers to the possible duplicate, `==` is not implemented for enumerations *with associated values*. You can file a bug report at Apple, but we cannot explain why the Swift people did not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
enum CompassPoint {
    case North
    case South
    case East
    case West
}

let isEqual = CompassPoint.North ==  CompassPoint.South
//false
```

another example:

```
enum CompassPoint: Int {
    case North = 1, South, East, West
}

let isEqual = CompassPoint.North ==  CompassPoint.South
//false
```

this will work also:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case SomeValue
    case OtherValue
    case ThirdValue
}


let areEqual = MyEnum.ThirdValue == MyEnum.ThirdValue
```

but your example the enum has different types.  You will only be able o compare various assigned to them.

Comment: Please see my edit for what is not working. Please consider deleting this answer as it address the problem stated in original question.